# Rules for modulus and multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

My question is rather simple as I'm interested about modulus and multiplication, specifically whether it holds that $(a*b)\,mod\,n=(a\,mod\,n)*(b\,mod\,n)$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of "$\text{mod} \,\, n$"? What have you tried so far? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Since $mod\,n$ produces the remainder from division by $n$, it is obviously true for the cases where either $a$ or $b$ are perfectly divisible by $n$ as the product would also be by nature of multiplication. I'm not quite sure about the other cases, although it seems to hold. I'm practically searching for a proof of why this works(or doesn't).

Comment: It is true that $(a\cdot b) \textrm{mod}n =((a \textrm{mod}n)\cdot (b \textrm{mod}n))\textrm{mod}n$. Try $a=5$, $b=8$, $n=3$ in your equation.

Comment: I allready though so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not quite, the correct rule is

$$(ab\bmod m)=((a\bmod m)(b\bmod m))\bmod m$$ because the product $(a\bmod m)(b\bmod m)$ can very well exceed $m$ (it actually lies in range $[0,(m-1)^2]$).

Comment: Yep, many people write $=$ for $\equiv$ and forget the additional modulo.

Comment: How to proof this?

Comment: @Buraian: to prove what ? That many people forget ?

Comment: The result, I've figured out how to do it now $a=p_1 m + r_1$ and $b=p_2 m + r_2$, multiplying and taking mod:

$$ ab mod m \equiv r_1 r_2 \mod m$$

Then $r_1 = a \mod m $ , $r_2 = b \mod m $

Answer (score 7):

$\begin{array}{}a\pmod n\equiv \tilde a\iff a=np+\tilde a\\
b\pmod n\equiv \tilde b\iff b=nq+\tilde b\end{array}$

$ab=n(npq+q\tilde a+p\tilde b)+\tilde a\tilde b\implies ab\equiv \tilde a\tilde b\pmod{n}$

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:*** $a=nr_1+s_1, b=nr_2+s_2$ where $r_1, r_2, s_1, s_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq s_1< n, 0 \leq s_2 < n$. Then
$$a\,\,(mod\,\, n)=?$$
$$b\,\,(mod \,\, n)=?$$
$$ab\,\, (mod\,\, n) = ?$$
Can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 1):

In modular arithmetic there are two equivalent expressions:
$$a \bmod n = a_1 \iff a \equiv a_1 (\bmod n)$$
$$b \bmod n = b_1 \iff b \equiv b_1 (\bmod n)$$
$$(ab) \bmod n = c_1 \iff (ab) \equiv c_1 (\bmod n)$$
According to the multiplication property (see: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)):
$$(ab) \equiv (a_1b_1) \equiv c_1 (\bmod n)$$
For example: $a=5,b=8,n=3$:
$$5 \equiv 2 (\bmod 3)$$
$$8 \equiv 2 (\bmod 3)$$
$$(5\cdot 8) \equiv (2\cdot2) \equiv 1 (\bmod 3)$$

Comment: $$\because a \equiv a_1 (\bmod n)  \iff a \bmod n = a_1$$
$$(ab) \equiv (a_1b_1) (\bmod n) \iff (ab) \bmod n = (a_1b_1) = (a \bmod n)(b \bmod n)$$
But, how do we get, $$(ab) \bmod n = (a_1b_1) \bmod n$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement

> *for all integers $a$ and $b$, $(ab)\bmod n=(a\bmod n)(b\bmod n)$*

only holds for $n=1$ or $n=2$. The case $n=1$ is trivial, as $a\bmod 1=0$ for every integer $a$. For $n=2$ it's easy as well, because $a\bmod 2=0$ if $a$ is even and $a\bmod 2=1$ if $a$ is odd (just check the four cases).

There is already a counterexample for $n=3$: indeed
$$
(2\cdot2)\bmod 3=1
\qquad
(2\bmod 3)(2\bmod 3)=4
$$
For general $n>2$ the counterexample is similar: take $a=b=n-1$; then
$$
(ab)\bmod n=(n^2-2n+1)\bmod n=1
$$
whereas
$$
(a\bmod n)(b\bmod n)=(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1=n(n-2)+1>1
$$